# Best way to get around the unique-constraint for many-to-many relationships in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a situation where I need to be able to add multiple copies of the same object to a many-to-many relationship.

Let's say that the problem is recording the types of furniture someone has. Here are my base models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Furniture(models.Model):
    furniture_name = models.CharField(max_length=100) #e.g. Chair, Sofa.
```

Lets say I want to record that Sam owns 3 chairs and 2 sofas. But I don't want to make more than one `sofa` object in the DB. How can I do this with a many-to-many relationship? The traditional many-to-many has a unique-constraint that prevents this.

I'm thinking of using a through table, with another field in the unique-constraint (date-purchased, or just a random string). Will that work?

Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Comment: What you need is to add a column on the pivot table between Person and Furniture. (I don't know Django but this could help you finding a valid answer)

Comment: There you go: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a through table is a good approach here, as everything will be DRY and pretty easy to use:

```
class Ownership:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    furniture = models.ForeignKey(Furniture, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    items_owned = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [
            'owner', 'furniture'
        ]

person = Person.objects.get(name='Bob')
furniture = Furniture.objects.get(furniture_name='Sofa')

# update the number of items owned
Ownership.objects.update_or_create(
    owner=person, furniture=furniture, defaults=dict(items_owned=3))

# get the number of items owned
person.ownership_set.get(furniture=furniture).items_owned

# or for example
Ownership.objects.get(owner__name='Bob', furniture__name='Sofa').items_owned
```

You can then abstract away this complex querying and updating logic with custom managers https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers

Comment: Thanks, that's a very informative answer. I especially appreciated the examples of how to fetch items_owned.

Comment: Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) states that `unique_together` may be deprecated in future in favor of `models.UniqueConstraint`. May be this answer should be updated accordingly